# MySQL Grant file permission to all users

Tags: mysql, sql-grant

I need to give file permission to all users in my MySQL database. This query for a single user works perfect

```
GRANT FILE ON *.* TO 'john'@'localhost';
```

When I want to give the file permission to all users on my database I tried the following query

```
GRANT FILE ON *.* TO '%'@'%';
```

But it didn't work. What do I need to do to give the file permission to all users? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use wild card characters to match all users with `GRANT` statements.

You need to specify the individual user accounts while specifying the **GRANT**

As per the `GRANT` syntax, you can use wildcard characters for database objects on which you have to give privileges, but not for the users.

Comment: I know that this doesn't work. I was hoping for a workaround instead of an answer which just says that it doesn't work.